# JS and GWT/smartGWT

Tags: javascript, gwt, smartgwt

Can a canvas smartgwt or gwt object interact with a canvas JS object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can have an object that does native JS methods in GWT that interacts on the raw canvas.  GWTCanvas is a more full featured library for GWT.

http://code.google.com/docreader/#p=google-web-toolkit-incubator&s=google-web-toolkit-incubator&t=GWTCanvas